# Differentiation under the integral sign for a $L^1$-valued function (shape derivative)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, oc.optimization-and-control, geometric-measure-theory, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$;
- $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open and $$\mathcal A:=\{\Omega\subseteq U:\Omega\text{ is bounded and open and }\partial\Omega\text{ is of class }C^{0,\:1}\};$$
- $E:=\bigcup_{\Omega\in\mathcal A}L^1(\Omega)$;
- $y:\mathcal A\to E$ with $$y(\Omega)\in L^1(\Omega)\;\;\;\text{for all }\Omega\in\mathcal A;\tag1$$
- $\tau>0$ and $T_t:U\to U$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism for $t\in[0,\infty)$ with $T_0=\operatorname{id}_D$ and $\det{\rm D}T_t(x)>0$ for all $(t,x)\in[0,\tau)\times U$;
- $V:=\bigcup_{t\in[0,\:\tau)}T_t(U)$
- $v:[0,\tau)\times V\to\mathbb R^d$ be differentiable in the second argument with $$v\left(t,T_t(x)\right)=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[0,\tau)\times U;\tag2$$
- $\Omega\in\mathcal A$ and $\Omega_t:=T_t(\Omega)$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$;
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$;
- $\sigma_{\partial\Omega}$ denote the surface measure on $\mathcal B(\partial\Omega)$;
- $\nu_{\partial\Omega}$ denote the unit outer normal field on $\partial\Omega$.

> There is the following well-known result: If $f\in L^1(V)$ is differentiable, then the functional $$\mathcal F(A):=\int_Af\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\;\;\;\text{for }A\in\mathcal A$$ is "shape differentiable at $\Omega$ in direction $v$", i.e. $$\frac{\mathcal F(\Omega_t)-\mathcal F(\Omega_0)}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\int_{\partial\Omega}f\langle v_0,\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\partial\Omega}\tag3.$$

Now let $Y:[0,\tau)\to E_d$ with $$\left.Y(t)\right|_{\Omega_t}=y(\Omega_t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau).$$ Then $y$ is called **shape differentiable at $\Omega$ in direction $v$** if $Y$ is Fréchet differentiable at $0$. In that case, $$y'(\Omega)(v):=\left.Y'(0)\right|_{\Omega}\tag4.$$

> How can we show that $(4)$ does not depend on the choice of $Y$?

Let $Y_i$ be two choices of $Y$. Clearly, $$0=\int_{\Omega_t}(Y_1(t)-Y_2(t))\varphi\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\tag5$$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(U)$.

> But why does differentiating $(5)$ with respect to $t$ yield $$0=\int_\Omega(Y_1'(0)-Y_2'(0))\varphi\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}+\int_{\partial\Omega}(Y_1(0)-Y_2(0))\varphi\langle v_0,\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\partial\Omega}\tag5?$$

The second term on the right-hand side of $(5)$ seems to be an application of $(3)$ for $f=Y_1(0)-Y_2(0))\varphi$. But where does the first term come from? It seems to be some kind of product rule which is applied here ...